# Show viewMap until user close it

Tags: python, android-intent

I would like to start a common intent ( `android.viewMap()` ) with waiting until the user close the activity.
I cannot determine the correct parameters to these functions:

```
mapIntent = droid.makeIntent("android.intent.action.RUN", droid.viewMap(dic["latitude"]+","+dic["longitude"]))
droid.startActivityIntent(mapIntent, True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem.

```
mapIntent = droid.makeIntent("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH", str(droid.viewMap(dic["latitude"]+","+dic["longitude"]))) 
droid.startActivityIntent(mapIntent, True)
```